# White line in div hides text (custom component)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am currently working in ReactJS together with some SCSS / CSS stylings.

However, I made a component, that lists number codecs on hover.
In normal state it's a div, that indicates a small or big damage size.
When you hover on it, it opens the listed mentioned above.

For some reason, I always have this white line, ditching my number coded so I can't be read. What did I miss? My code is below.

**Livedemo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cun89d?file=App.js**

> DAMAGE_SIZE_STATUSES = {
> GREEN: 'green',
> YELLOW: 'yellow',
> RED: 'red',
> };

'index.js'

```
...

  const criticality =
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
    critical && criticalConditions.some((condition) => condition.fulfilled)
      ? DAMAGE_SIZE_STATUSES.RED
      : critical
      ? DAMAGE_SIZE_STATUSES.YELLOW
      : DAMAGE_SIZE_STATUSES.GREEN;

  const criticalityTextKey = getIndicatorStatusTextKey(criticality);
  const criticalityIcon = getIndicatorStatusIcon(criticality);

return
<div className={classNames('DamageSizeIndicator', criticality)}>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="title">
          <div className="criticality">
            {criticalityIcon && <Icon type={criticalityIcon} theme="filled" />}
            {t(criticalityTextKey)}
          </div>
          <div className="condition" />
        </div>
        {critical ? (
          <ul className="critical-icds">
            {criticalConditions.map((icd) => (
              <li
                key={`critical-icd_${icd.code}`}
                className={classNames({
                  'icd-fulfilled': icd.fulfilled,
                  'icd-unfulfilled': !icd.fulfilled,
                })}
              >
                <div className="icd-description">
                  <span>ICD {icd.code}</span>
                  <Tooltip title={icd.description}>{icd.description}</Tooltip>
                </div>
                <div className="icd-condition">
                  <span>
                    <Icon
                      type={
                        icd.fulfilled ? 'check-circle' : 'exclamation-circle'
                      }
                    />
                    {t(getConditionFulfilledTextKey(icd.fulfilled))}
                  </span>
                  {icd.condition}
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ) : null}
```

styling.scss

```
@import 'src/app/variables.scss';

.DamageSizeIndicator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 72px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 450;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 25px;

  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;

  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: $overlay-shadow;
    border-radius: $overlay-radius;
    position: absolute;

    .title,
    .critical-icds {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      flex: 1;

      border-radius: $overlay-radius;
      padding: 10px;

      transition: 0.2s linear all;

      i {
        margin-right: 0.5em;
      }
    }

    .title {
      background: $colorSubtleWhite;
      font-size: $titleFontSize;

      .condition {
        display: none;
        white-space: nowrap;

        padding-left: 0.5em;
      }
    }

    .critical-icds {
      background: $colorSubtleGray;
      font-size: $subTitleFontSize;

      display: none;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;

      flex-direction: column;

      li {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        span {
          color: $colorGray;
          white-space: nowrap;
          padding-right: 0.5em;
        }

        .icd-description,
        .icd-condition {
          color: $colorLightBlack;
          position: relative;

          max-width: 350px;
          overflow: hidden;
          white-space: nowrap;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }

        &.icd-unfulfilled {
          .icd-condition span {
            color: $colorIndicatorYellow;
          }
        }

        &.icd-fulfilled {
          .icd-condition span {
            color: $colorIndicatorGreen;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &:hover {
    /* cursor: pointer; */

    .content {
      .title {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;

        .condition {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      .critical-icds {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;

        display: flex;
        line-height: inherit;

        li:not(:last-child) {
          margin-bottom: 1rem;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.green {
    .content {
      box-shadow: none;

      .title .criticality {
        color: $colorIndicatorGray;
      }
    }

    pointer-events: none;
  }

  &.yellow {
    .content .title .criticality {
      color: $colorIndicatorYellow;
    }
  }

  &.red {
    .content .title .criticality {
      color: $colorIndicatorRed;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: three]

Comment: This type of problem is often best addressed in the rendered HTML and CSS. Can you show a working snippet demo of that?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Don't tag your post titles.

Comment: @isherwood I added a live demo-

Comment: I don't see the white line on the demo.

Comment: Try adding `z-index: 1000` to the **.content** class, it look like something is overlapping your **.content** class.

Comment: @Anton this didn't help sadly.

Comment: I played with the  flex-direction: column; attribute. When I change this to something else I don't have the issue anymore, but it's not the design I want to use!

Comment: That is strange behavior, try removing `margin-bottom: 1rem` from the `li:not(:last-child)`.